# How do i remove the redirect layer covering a post - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hey i found this pre-written jQuery script and im wondering if someone could do me a big favour and show me where the script is so i can remove the layer over the post that it that redirects someone when clicked.. Thanks :)

Source code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //when the DOM is ready 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //settings on top
            var doindex = 'comments.php?item_id=';
            var initialPosts = <?php echo get_posts(0,$_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
            //function that creates posts
            var postHandler = function(postsJSON) {
                $.each(postsJSON,function(i,post) {

                    //post url
                    var postURL  = '' + doindex + post.item_id;
                    var id = 'post-' + post.ID;
                    //create the HTML
                    $('<div></div>')
                    .addClass('post')
                    .attr('id',id)
                    //generate the HTML
.html('<table width="244" height="101" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2" ><tr>    <td height="24" colspan="2" bgcolor="#0270B7"><table width="410" border="0"><tr> <td width="404" height="20" class="username"><a href="../profile.php?user=' + post.username + '" class="username">&nbsp;' + post.username + '<span class="name">&nbsp;&nbsp;' + post.name + '</span></a></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr> <td width="51" bgcolor="#Edeff4"><span class="thum"><img src="' + post.thumnailpath + '" alt="" width="50" height="50" /></span></td><td width="355" height="50" bgcolor="#Edeff4" class="content">&nbsp;' + post.item_content  + '</td></tr><tr><td height="19" colspan="2" bgcolor="#Edeff4" class="content"><table width="404" border="0"> <tr class="post-title"><td width="171" height="28" class="links"> <a href="comment.php?id=' + post.item_id + '"  class="post-title">&nbsp;<span class="post-title">comment </span></a><a href="#"  class="post-title">(' + post.likecount + '</a><a href="comment.php?id=' + post.item_id + '"  class="post-title"><span class="post-title">)</span></a> <span class="post-title"><a href="#"  class="post-title">likes (' + post.likecount + ')</a></span></td><td width="223" >' + post.timeago + '</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>')



                    .click(function() {
                        window.location = postURL;
                    })
                    //inject into the container
                    .appendTo($('#posts'))
                    .hide()
                    .slideDown(250,function() {
                        if(i == 0) {
                            $.scrollTo($('div#' + id));
                        }
                    });
                }); 
            };
            //place the initial posts in the page
            postHandler(initialPosts);
            //first, take care of the "load more"
            //when someone clicks on the "load more" DIV
            var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;
            var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;
            var loadMore = $('#load-more');
            //load event / ajax
            loadMore.click(function(){
                //add the activate class and change the message
                loadMore.addClass('activate').text('Loading...');
                //begin the ajax attempt
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'jquery-version.php',
                    data: {
                        'start': start,
                        'desiredPosts': desiredPosts
                    },
                    type: 'get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(responseJSON) {
                        //reset the message
                        loadMore.text('Load More');
                        //increment the current status
                        start += desiredPosts;
                        //add in the new posts
                        postHandler(responseJSON);
                    },
                    //failure class
                    error: function() {
                        //reset the message
                        loadMore.text('Oops! Try Again.');
                    },
                    //complete event
                    complete: function() {
                        //remove the spinner
                        loadMore.removeClass('activate');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking this out:

```
.click(function() {
  window.location = postURL;
})
```